# SQL Server counting remote connections

Tags: sql-server, database-connection

I have an SQL server database which is used by an asp.net application using ado.net.
The server version is 10.50.1600.1 
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL
Users have complained about orphaned connections and connections exceeding limit eventually.

I started management studio on my laptop and connected remotely to the server. I use the same ADO.NET user id for connecting to management studio.
The user does not have permissions to view Dynamic management views or start profiler or Activity monitor.

I want to check the # of connections opened by the same user. (I use the ADP.NET user for connecting management studio.)

I have tried `sp_who` and `sp_who2` as well as selecting from the sys.processes view, but I only get a report on my local connections.

I was expecting to get all connections for the same user. How can I do this?

Comment: you need `VIEW SERVER STATE` permissions and `SELECT` permissions on master..sysprocesses to be able to view the connection details from all users to the database in question.

Comment: Thanks viktor , I thought it was a permission problem but I couldnt see any docs stating this. Thanks for this and I will request the DBA for select permissions. But I am really wanting to see only connections from the same user as ADO.NET connects as same user.So I am not sure-Is it because the ado.net connections are remote connections?

Comment: once you have the permissions, you can filter on the hostname/program_name/hostprocess which ever is appropriately is set by those ADO.NET remote connections.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You need admin user for this, least priveleges user can't access such info.